# Shifting the derivative outside the integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, calculus, dirac-delta-distributions

In [page 62](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.fisica.net/mecanica-quantica/Shankar%2520-%2520Principles%2520of%2520quantum%2520mechanics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjQmZLg9cHbAhXVfCsKHcynDcsQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw3t59bGXXAPQE5joxcE1CKZ) of Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics, the author conveys the following: $$\int \delta'( x-x') f(x') dx' = \int \frac{d\delta(x-x')}{dx}f(x')dx'= \frac{d}{dx} \int \delta(x-x') f(x') dx'= \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$

Where $\delta(x-x')$ is the Dirac-Delta function. Under what conditions can one shift the derivative outside the integral?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Although distributions in place of functions make this a little more complicated. With dirac-delta functions, you can also get the same result via integrating by parts.